# converting a string to xml

Tags: xml, string, xslt

I am trying to achieve the below:

Input

```xml
<Info>50114356,50114354,50114243,</Info>
```

I need to achieve:

```
<ROOT>
<ITEM>
    <CODE>50114356</CODE>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
    <CODE>50114354</CODE>
</ITEM>
<ITEM>
    <CODE>50114243</CODE>
</ITEM></ROOT>
```

the ITEMs aren't fixed in number so it has  to be dynamically tackled.

I am get the count of the items via:

```xml
<xsl:value-of select="string-length(//Info) - string-length(translate(//Info, ',', ''))"/>
```

Now I need to apply a FINITE LOOP. How to do that.

Cheers,
Vicky

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: XSLT processor is SAXON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use XSLT 2.0+, this is trivial using `tokenize()`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(Info, ',')[string()]">
    <ITEM>
        <CODE>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </CODE>
    </ITEM>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: is it also possible to remove duplicate from the list -<Info>50114356,50114354,50114243,50114354,</Info>

Comment: Yes, use: `<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(tokenize(Info, ','))[string()]">`.